# Drawing "advanced" primitives in Marmalade

Tags: drawing, primitive, marmalade

I've been looking around for examples on drawing more advanced primitives in Marmalade SDK.

Examples: Speech bubble, rounded rectangle, star etc.

I'm not sure if Iw2d or IwGx is the correct path to go. I've also looked at Cairo, and that might be an option, although it is a bit more than what I need.

Anyone worked with Marmalade SDK and drawing without the use of sprites/textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to use Iw2D. It is not simpler then IwGX.
You should use IwGX or OpenGL ES with sprites and textures.

I use OpenGL ES 2.0.

I do not know other graphics libs to draw primitives but marmalade github has cairo
https://github.com/marmalade/cairo

It is very old lib.

Comment: Sorry for beeing slow to reply. IwGX + OpenGL ES looks like the way to go. I've found quite a lot of examples (googling) for drawing primitives in OpenGL and it seems doable to _port_ most to IwGX. Iw2D seems to be for simple sprite 2d only.

Comment: Iw2D relates to old platforms like Nokia with Symbian with GPU. Right now we target devices with GPU and OpenGL ES 2.0. With OpenGL ES 2.0 you less dependent on Marmalade. GX has some goodies like texture loading, default shaders.